# Check for any diffs between local and remote files (like rsync -n)

Tags: ssh, diff, rsync

I have two alias that I use to "get" and "put" files from a central location.  I use these two aliases to sync files.  It lets me access and update my files from any of my various workstations.

The aliases are the following:

```
alias filesget='rsync -nvhaulz --delete me@X.X.X.X:files/ /home/me/files/'
alias filesput='rsync -nvhaulz --delete /home/me/files/ me@X.X.X.X:files/'
```

So, when I arrive at a workstation in the morning, for example, I would enter `filesget`, and then after finishing my work, I would enter `filesput`.  It's a very basic and simple system. (And it works great for me.)

Now, if for some reason I can't remember whether I have done a "get" or a "put", and need to check, I use the following `-n` optioned versions of the `filesget` and `filesput` aliases.

```
alias filesgettest='rsync -nvhaulz --delete me@X.X.X.X:files/ /home/me/files/'
alias filesputtest='rsync -nvhaulz --delete /home/me/files/ me@X.X.X.X:files/'
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to check whether my files are out of perfect sync than by using the `filesgettest` and `filesputtest` aliases.

What is a better single command for achieving what I achieve with these two aliases?  For example, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16661/how-can-i-diff-two-redhat-linux-servers/16665#16665) it was suggested to use the command:

```
rsync -ani --delete / root@remotehost:/
```

But will this suggested command check for exactly the same changes that running both `filesgettest` and `filesputtest` checks for?

Comment: Sounds like you ought to investigate `unison`...

Comment: @twalberg Cool, I'll check this out.  Might be exactly what I need...